# Swift App Auto-Login not working

Tags: swift, cocoa, authentication, view, autostart

I followed this tutorial here to create an auto-login feature for ma Swift app: https://theswiftdev.com/2015/09/17/first-os-x-tutorial-how-to-launch-an-os-x-app-at-login/

The tutorial is pretty straightforward - the only problem is that I simply can not make it work with my app - it just doesn't work.

I have created a new project for the auto-login with the identifier "com.sascha-simon.com.NetWorkerAutoStarter".

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    let mainIdentifier = "com.sascha-simon.Mac.NetWorker"
    let running = NSWorkspace.shared().runningApplications
    var alreadyRunning = false

    for app in running
    {
        if app.bundleIdentifier == mainIdentifier
        {
            alreadyRunning = true
            break
        }
    }

    if !alreadyRunning
    {
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.terminate), name: NSNotification.Name("killme"), object: mainIdentifier)

        let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath as NSString
        var components = path.pathComponents
        components.removeLast()
        components.removeLast()
        components.removeLast()
        components.append("MacOS")
        components.append("NetWorker")

        let newPath = NSString.path(withComponents: components)
        NSWorkspace.shared().launchApplication(newPath)
    }
    else
    {
        self.terminate()
    }
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

func terminate()
{
    NSApp.terminate(nil)
}
```

My Main-App has the identifier "com.sascha-simon.NetWorker"

AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    let starterIdentifier = "com.sascha-simon.NetWorkerAutoStarter"

    var startedAtLogin = false
    for app in NSWorkspace.shared().runningApplications
    {
        if app.bundleIdentifier == starterIdentifier
        {
            startedAtLogin = true
            break
        }
    }

    if startedAtLogin
    {
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().post(name: NSNotification.Name("killme"), object: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
    }
}
```

I have a NSPopup with a checkbox to enable the auto login:

```
    @IBAction func startOSCheckedChange(_ sender: NSButton)
{
    let value = sender.state == 1
    SMLoginItemSetEnabled("com.sascha-simon.NetWorkerAutoStarter" as CFString, value)
}
```

The method returns true. I have exported the developer-id signed app, started it, enabled the auto login, logged out...and the app didn't start.

I have set an alert to the auto start project and the problem is, that it seems that the project is not started (and therefore the main project isn't started).

First I thought that I have to add a storyboard/MainMenu.xib file to the project (and add the key to the info.plist) but that didn't help either.

What could I have forgotten?

Comment: Where have you placed your application bundle? It should be in the /Applications folder (otherwise you may encounter issues with SMLoginItemSetEnabled).

Comment: Did you find issue ?